# Problem related to Python insert() method

Tags: python, list, insert, append

I make a list of the first 10 square numbers. Here’s how I might put the first 10 square numbers into a list:

```
    square=[]
    for i in range(1,10):
       square.insert(-1,i**2)
    print(square)
```

I expect the output of code to be 
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,] 
but the actual output is 
[4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 1]
How I can fix this problem and please can you explain why my code isn't running

Comment: Why are you using `insert` instead of `append`?

Comment: Or a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way to do it in Python, you should write something like this instead:

```
square = [i**2 for i in range(1,10)]
```

The reason why you get that result though is that inserting on -1st position will insert the number to the position before the last one in list, so you'll get [1], [2,1], [2,4,1] etc. as you iterate through the loop.

Comment: How i can write it with (-) ?

Comment: @FuadFatali What do you mean with -? [i**2 for i in range(-1,-10,-1)] :D , but I don't think that's what you wanted, so please explain.

Comment: Works very well. It's list comprehension

Comment: I can write it with append, but I also want to write it with square.insert(-1,"i**2"). My question is that can i do it? If yes, how i can do it?

Answer (score 1):

There may be typo in your code:

`square.insert(-1, i**2)`

may be:

`square.insert(i, i**2)`

[See a working demo here](https://repl.it/repls/NoteworthyBonyNumericalanalysis).

Comment: I can't understand what is the wrong in my code, because i write square.insert(0,i**2) it works and output is [81, 64, 49, 36, 25, 16, 9, 4, 1], but when i write reverse it like square.insert(-1,i**2) i can't get expected output([1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81,] ) , it doens't work. Can you explain the logic of code?

Comment: @FuadFatali There's an explanation in the answer from bruno0.

Comment: Oops, I misread it, I thought you wrote `1` where you wrote `i`.

Comment: sir it;s not 1 it's i

Comment: I know, I just said that.

Comment: It would be better if you used code formatting, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
square=[]
num=10
for i in range(1,num):
    square.insert(num,i**2)
print(square)
```

The insert function exactly takes two arguments

```
list_name.insert(index, element)
```

now in the above code every element is trying to be inserted on 10th index whereas the list is empty so every element is filling the empty place before the 10th index. And if give -1 as an index then the increment for index will be -1,0,1,2,3,4,5... so that's why you got

```
>[4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 1]
```

Comment: it gives the desired output:                                                                          [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

Comment: You should explain HOW it works. Put the explanation in the answer.

Comment: I'm not that much good at explanation but i hope i explained well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `append` function. It should look something like this:

```
square=[]
for i in range(1, 10):
    square.append(i**2)
print(square)
```

Comment: This is the same as john gonidelis's answer.

Comment: İ know append() method, but i want to write code with insert and (-)

Comment: @FuadFatali: Why do you want _"code with insert and (-)"_? If there is an additional constraint to your task, you have to explain it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `insert`, use `len(square)` rather than `-1` as the index argument.

When you call `insert()`, it inserts the new element before the element at the given index. When the index is negative, it counts from the end. So `square.insert(-1, newvalue)` means to insert the new element *before* the last element, not after it.

The first time, the list is empty, so there's no last element to put it before, and it just appends to the list. But on all other iterations, it inserts before that element, so it stays at the end.

If you use `len(square)` as the index, that's after the last element, so inserting before it puts it at the end.

```
square=[]
for i in range(1,10):
   square.insert(len(square),i**2)
print(square)
```

I don't think there's any way to do it using a negative index.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the order with `-1`. This should be:

```
square = []

for i in range(1, 10):
    square.insert(10, i**2)
print(square)
```

output:

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
square=[]
for i in range(1, 9):
    square.insert(i,i**2)
    print(square)
```

Your method does not work because you start from `-1` which is equivalent to the end of your list and after that the `insert()` function cycles to the start of your list in order to fill it in.